Ruby: How to list methods declared in the main scope
In vanilla ruby, if I create methods in the default main scope:
def asdf
    puts "asdf"
end

def qwer
    puts "qwer"
end

How do I list these functions?
I have tried the following with no luck:
methods.grep(/asdf|qwer/)
self.methods.grep(/asdf|qwer/)
Object.methods.grep(/asdf|qwer/)
Object.instance_methods.grep(/asdf|qwer/)

I'm running ruby on Windows 10, installed via https://scoop.sh/:
> ruby --version
ruby 3.3.1 (2024-04-23 revision c56cd86388) [x64-mingw-ucrt]


Methods created in main scope (these are methods not functions) are private visibitility.
This means that you are looking for them in the wrong place.
Instead, do private_methods while you are in main scope as this will list the private methods that are defined for Object, which is where main scope is.
Example:
def asdf
    puts "asdf"
end

def qwer
    puts "qwer"
end

puts private_methods.grep(/asdf/)


In your title, you ask [bold italic emphasis mine]:

How to list methods declared in the main scope

But in the question body you write:

I create methods in the default main scope

These are not the same thing!
The general syntax for defining a method in Ruby is something like this:
def definee.methodname(parameters)
  # body
end

# or

def definee.methodname(parameters) = some_expression

For example
def (o = Object.new).foo(bar) = 2 * bar

o.foo(21)
#=> 42

This will create a method named methodname on the object which is the result of evaluating the expression definee (or more precisely in that object's singleton class).
This poses the question: where does a method get created if no definee is specified? Ruby has the concept of a default definee. Normally, the default definee is the closest lexically enclosing module. But in your case, there is no enclosing module, so that doesn't help us.
You might think that the default definee at the top-level would be the singleton class of the top-level main object, but that is wrong. For method definitions at the top-level, there is a special rule: the default definee becomes the Object class, and furthermore, the method becomes private by default unless explicitly defined otherwise.
So, let's look at what is happening with your code:

methods.grep(/asdf|qwer/)
self.methods.grep(/asdf|qwer/)


In Ruby, self is the implicit receiver, so these two are actually the same. At the top-level, self is the unnamed top-level object, typically called main. So, what you are asking for here is the list of all public methods that can be invoked on the main object. Since asdf and qwer are private, they won't show up in this list.

Object.methods.grep(/asdf|qwer/)


What you are asking for here is the list of all public methods that can be invoked on the Object class object. Note that this is not the methods that are defined in Object, this is the list of methods that can be called on Object. (Although, since Object is a class and classes are objects in Ruby, the Object class object is an instance of the Object, i.e., an instance of itself(!!!). Therefore, the list of methods that can be called on Object includes all the methods that are defined in Object plus the methods defined in Object's singleton class. IOW, the list of methods that can be called on Object is a superset of the methods defined in Object.)
So, your methods would show up here if they were public or if you had asked for private methods, but the reason they would show up is convoluted and probably not the reason you would think they do.

Object.instance_methods.grep(/asdf|qwer/)


What you are asking for here is the list of all public methods that are defined in Object. The reason your methods don't show up here is that they are private.
What you are most likely looking for is:
Object.private_instance_methods.grep(/asdf|qwer/)
#=> [:asdf, :qwer]

or, maybe
private_methods.grep(/asdf|qwer/)
#=> [:asdf, :qwer]

But I think the first one is the one you want. Remember that these two don't do the same thing.
vgoff's answer states:

do private_methods while you are in main scope as this will list the private methods that are defined for Object, which is where main scope is.

However, it is important to understand why this is incorrect. As the documentation for Object#private_methods states [bold italic emphasis mine]:

private_methods(all=true) → array
Returns the list of private methods accessible to obj. If the all parameter is set to false, only those methods in the receiver will be listed.

The "list of methods accessible to some object" is not the same as the list of methods defined in the object's class (and its superclasses), since there could also be methods defined in the object's singleton class.
Which means the first part of the statement:

[…] this will list the private methods that are defined for Object […]

is incorrect, since the private_methods method will not list the private methods that are defined for Object but the private methods that are accessible to the unnamed top-level main object. This is not just an academic distinction, there really are such methods:
private_methods - Object.private_methods
#=> [:include, :define_method, :autoload, :autoload?]

The second half of the statement is not technically incorrect, but somewhat misleading:

[…] Object, which is where main scope is.

There are four scopes in Ruby:

the lexical scope for local variables,
self, i.e., the scope for instance variables, as well as the default implicit receiver,
the default definee, i.e., where methods are defined if the definee is not explicitly specified, and
constant scope.

Generally, when Rubyists talk about "scope" without any qualifier, they are talking about the lexical scope for local variables or maybe, if it is clear from context, self. However, in this case, the relevant scope is the default definee, and it would be clearer to point that out specifically.
At the top-level, the lexical scope for local variables is the script body. self is the unnamed top-level object, typically called main.

I guess it also depends on how you define "methods that are defined in Object" because technically speaking (by default) there are no methods defined in Object as every method "that can be called on Object" are actually defined against a different class e.g. Object.instance_methods(false) #=> [] as well as Object.methods(false) #=> []....

...The only exceptions I can find are that delegate.rb defines the private instance method DelgateClass in the Object "scope" and initialize and inherited are purported to be private methods defined against Object even though they are technically defined for the class Class.

Would this be an even better solution? Object.private_instance_methods(false).grep(/asdf|qwer/). Object.private_instance_methods(false) only lists my own methods (plus :DelegateClass).

It might be worth noting that Ruby's built-in global methods that can be called in functional form (as the docs put it) are defined a little different, as so-called module functions in Kernel:
method(:puts)
#=> #<Method: Object(Kernel)#puts>
#                       ^
#                  actual owner

Kernel.method(:puts)
#=> #<Method: Kernel.puts>

You can easily replicate this via module_function:
module Kernel
  def qwer
    puts "qwer"
  end
  module_function :qwer
end

method(:qwer)
#=> #<Method: Object(Kernel)#qwer>

Kernel.method(:qwer)
#=> #<Method: Kernel.qwer>

Such method can be called in the top-level scope (or within the scope of any object) without a receiver, or directly as a class method on Kernel. Otherwise it is private: (just like puts)
qwer        # prints: qwer
Kernel.qwer # prints: qwer
123.qwer    # NoMethodError: private method `qwer' called for 123:Fixnum

